# How to use gnupg in an AWS Lambda function

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, python-3.8, gnupg

I have a local python code which GPG encrypts a file. I need to convert this to AWS Lambda, once a file has been added to AWS S3 which triggers this lambda.

My local code

```
import os
import os.path
import time
import sys
gpg = gnupg.GPG(gnupghome='/home/ec2-user/.gnupg')

path = '/home/ec2-user/2021/05/28/'
ptfile = sys.argv[1]

with open(path + ptfile, 'rb')as f:
        status = gpg.encrypt_file(f, recipients=['user@email.com'], output=path + ptfile + ".gpg")

print(status.ok)
print(status.stderr)
```

This works great when I execute this file as *python3 encrypt.py file.csv* and the result is *file.csv.gpg*

I'm trying to move this to AWS Lambda and invoked when a file.csv is uploaded to S3.

```
import json
import urllib.parse
import boto3
import gnupg
import os
import os.path
import time

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'], encoding='utf-8')
    
    try:
        gpg = gnupg.GPG(gnupghome='/.gnupg')
        ind = key.rfind('/')
        ptfile = key[ind + 1:]
        with open(ptfile, 'rb')as f:
            status = gpg.encrypt_file(f, recipients=['email@company.com'], output= ptfile + ".gpg")
        print(status.ok)
        print(status.stderr)
```

My AWS Lambda code zip created a folder structure in AWS
[image]

The error I see at runtime is **[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'gnupg'
Traceback (most recent call last):**

Comment: For a start, you'll need to [Deploy Python Lambda functions with .zip file archives - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package.html) to include the `gnupg` library. Any files required by the process (eg private keys) would need to be included in the Zip or downloaded from S3.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I updated my code structure and notice a runtime error.

Comment: The `gnupg` library is not a standard Python library. It needs to be included as a **deployment package** so that Python can use the library (not just your `.gnupg` directory). This is the same situation as trying to run your program on a new computer that does not have `gnupg` installed -- you would need to install it with `pip`. In the case of the Lambda function, you would do that installation in a virtual environment, then package the result into the zip file, as per the instructions linked in my previous comment.

Answer (score 6):

You can create a `gpg` binary suitable for use by python-gnupg on AWS Lambda from the [GnuPG 1.4 source](https://www.gnupg.org/download/). You will need

- GCC and associated tools (`sudo yum install -y gcc make glibc-static` on Amazon Linux 2)
- pip
- zip

After downloading the GnuPG source package and verifying its signature, build the binary with

```
$ tar xjf gnupg-1.4.23.tar.bz2
$ cd gnupg-1.4.23
$ ./configure
$ make CFLAGS='-static'
$ cp g10/gpg /path/to/your/lambda/
```

You will also need the `gnupg.py` module from python-gnupg, which you can fetch using pip:

```
$ cd /path/to/your/lambda/
$ pip install -t . python-gnupg
```

Your Lambda’s source structure will now look something like this:

```
.
├── gnupg.py
├── gpg
└── lambda_function.py
```

Update your function to pass the location of the `gpg` binary to the python-gnupg constructor:

```
gpg = gnupg.GPG(gnupghome='/.gnupg', gpgbinary='./gpg')
```

Use `zip` to package the Lambda function:

```
$ chmod o+r gnupg.py lambda_function.py 
$ chmod o+rx gpg
$ zip lambda_function.zip gnupg.py gpg lambda_function.py
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, I tried above approach but I am keep getting following error:

raise OSError(msg)g.py", line 945, in __init__y='./gpg'): Unable to run gpg (./gpg) - it may not be available.
END

I am building AWS Lambda function, It works fine in Python Notebook

Comment: I wonder if it's possible to just download the GnuPG binary rather than compiling from the sources

Answer (score 2):

Since there are some system dependencies required to use gpg within python i.e `gnupg` itself, you will need to build your lambda code using the container runtime environment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-images.html

Using docker will allow you to install underlying system dependencies, as well as import your keys.

Dockerfile will look something like this:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install gnupg

# copy handler file
COPY app.py <path-to-keys> ./

# Add keys to gpg
RUN gpg --import <path-to-private-key>
RUN gpg --import <path-to-public-key>

# Install dependencies and open port
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

CMD ["app.lambda_handler"]
```

`app.py` would be your lambda code. Feel free to copy any necessary files besides the main lambda handler.

Once the container image is built and uploaded. The lambda can now use the image (including all of its dependencies). The lambda code will run within the containerized environment which contains both gnupg and your imported keys.

Resources:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-image.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-images.html
https://medium.com/@julianespinel/how-to-use-python-gnupg-to-decrypt-a-file-into-a-docker-container-8c4fb05a0593

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to add a [lambda layer to](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html) your python lambda.

You need to make a virtual environment in which you `pip install gnupg` and then put all the installed python packages in a zip file, which you upload to aws as a lambda layer. This lambda layer can then be used in all lambdas where you need gnupg. To create the lamba layer you basically do:

```
python3.9 -m venv my_venv
 ./my_venv/bin/pip3.9 install gnupg
cp -r ./my_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ python
zip -r lambda_layer.zip python
```

Where the python version above has to match that of the python function in your lambda.

If you don't want to use layers you can additionally do:

```
zip -r lambda_layer.zip ./.gnupg
zip lambda_layer.zip lambda_funtion.py
```

And you get a zip file that you can use as a [lambda deployment package](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-package.html#gettingstarted-package-zip)

Answer (score 1):

The python-gnupg package requires you to have a working installation of the `gpg` executable, as mentioned in their official docs' [Deployment Requirements](https://gnupg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#); I am yet to find a way to access a `gpg` executable from lambda.

Answer (score 1):

gpg is now already installed in
`public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8`.

However despite that does not seem to be available from Lambda.
So you still need to get the gpg executable into the Lambda environment.

I did it using a docker image.

My Dockerfile is just:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8

COPY .venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ ./
COPY test_gpg.py .

CMD ["test_gpg.lambda_handler"]
```

`.venv` is the directory with my python virtualenv containing
the python packages I need.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using a Dockerfile image as the library is already available in one of the Amazon Linux or Lambda Python base images provided by AWS that you can find here https://gallery.ecr.aws/lambda/python (in the tag images tab you will find all the Python versions needed based on your requirements).

You will need to create the following 3 files in your dev environment:

- Dockerfile
- requirements.txt
- lambda script

The requirements.txt contains the python-gnupg for the import and all the other libraries based on your requirements:

```
boto3==1.15.11            # via -r requirements.in
urllib3==1.25.10          # via botocore
python-gnupg==0.5.0       # required for gpg encryption
```

This is the Dockerfile:

```
# Python 3.9 lambda base image
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.9

# Install pip-tools so we can manage requirements
RUN yum install python-pip -y

# Copy requirements.txt file locally
COPY requirements.txt ./

# Install dependencies into current directory
RUN python3.9 -m pip install -r requirements.txt

# Copy lambda file locally
COPY s3_to_sftp_batch.py .

# Define handler file name
CMD ["s3_to_sftp_batch.on_trigger_event_test"]
```

Then inside your lambda code add:

```
# define library path to point system libraries
os.environ["LD_LIBRARY_PATH"] = "/usr/bin/"

# create instance of GPG class and specify path that contains gpg binary
gpg = gnupg.GPG(gnupghome='/tmp', gpgbinary='/usr/bin/gpg')
```

Save these files then go to AWS ECR and create a Private repo then go to the repo and in the top right corner go to `View push commands` and run them to push your image in AWS.
Finally create your Lambda function using the container image.